# How to solve a stochastic differential equation

Tags: thermodynamics, probability, equilibrium, differential-equations, stochastic-processes

This is something I’ve been puzzled about over the past week or so. How do you go about getting the equilibrium probability distribution solution for a stochastic differential equation, like Smoluchowski?

Comment: This is mathematics, not physics.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how pass from the [Langevin equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation) to  the corresponding [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation). The highlighted Fokker-Planck link has a decent  explanation.